# Git Hook Scripting on Windows 7

Tags: git

I am following the first simple example in the [Git Hooks Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-hooks) tutorial, but putting the following line in my `pre-commit` hook file throws an "**ambiguous redirect**" error message when I do `$ git commit`.

I cannot find relevant info to this error. What am I doing wrong with this line?

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "# Please include a useful commit message!" > $1
```

I use `git version 2.10.2.windows.1`

Comment: Use `#!/bin/bash -x` for debugging purposes

Comment: Du you have a (Unix-) Shell `sh`or `bash` installed? If you use it on Windows, did you select `bash` during your Installation and included in the `PATH`?

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch When I uncomment that line and add `-x`, upon committing, I get: `error: cannot spawn .git/hooks/pre-commit: No such file or directory` Should I leave the `#` as is?

Comment: Details could be operating system specific. Please **edit your question** to give a lot more details (and version of `git`). Don't comment your question, but *improve it* a lot, give the exact `git` command that you run. What is the name of the file you are committing? Does it have spaces? Without a lot more details, your question is unclear.

Comment: @milbrandt I am on Windows 7 and I believe I have bash installed, because when I do `$ echo $0` I get `/usr/bin/bash`. Am I right? What else should I do?

Comment: The example is for `prepare-commit-msg`, you are trying to impl `pre-commit`

Comment: Still not enough details, even after the first edit. Try to make some [MCVE], so show the `git` commands and give the name of relevant files

Comment: @max630 Thank you. I failed to notice that...

Comment: A `pre-commit` hook does not take any parameter, so `$1` is ambiguous here. Its value is empty.

Comment: @max630 Many thanks. That was spot on. It runs now as it should, bringing up the commit dialogue with the # message.

Comment: @ElpieKay Thank you. You are absolutely right. I should have placed it in the `prepare-commit-msg` hook file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to *max630* and *ElpieKay* users, I realized that I was using the `echo "# Please include a useful commit message!" > $1` in the wrong hook file.

Also, I did not know that a `pre-commit` hook dida not take any parameter, so `$1` was indeed ambiguous there. Its value was actually empty.

I placed the little snippet in the `prepare-commit-msg` hook file and it works as [this](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-hooks) tutorial stated.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `> $1` and it will work fine.

I took hint from user9141560's answer